# Callback for variable?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have the following code:

```
# Import Libraries

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash 
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import datetime 

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

date_cols = ["date"]
df = pd.read_csv('base.csv', parse_dates=date_cols)

fig=px.bar(df,x='date',y='value_likes',color='type', barmode='group', 
        color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.deep, template='plotly_white'
        )

likes = df['value_likes'].iloc[-1]


app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server
app.title = "CSV"

app.layout = html.Div([
  dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=10*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        ),
  dbc.Container([
      html.H1("REALTIME MONITORING"),
      html.H4("%s" % likes),
      dcc.Interval(id="progress-interval", n_intervals=0, interval=500),
      dcc.Graph(id='graph', figure=fig)
  ],)

])

@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('interval-component', "n_intervals")]
)

def streamFig3(value):
    
    global df
    
    dfglobal = pd.read_csv('base.csv',dtype={'date':'string'})
    likes = dfglobal['value_likes'].iloc[-1]
    fig=px.bar(dfglobal,x='date',y='value_likes',color='type', barmode='group',
        color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.deep_r, template='plotly_white'
        )

    return(fig)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This code reads the csv every 10 seconds and updates the bar graph accordingly.
**However** it's not updating the variable **likes** that remains static after the first load.
Is there a way to make a callback so that **likes** also updates?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to add likes as global inside streamFig3.

Comment: @VascoLudovico not quite sure I understand what you mean by that, sorry

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but  it seemed to me that you would want 'likes' variable inside streamFig3 to be global. The way it is it's just a local variable.

Comment: @VascoLudovico adding 

```def streamFig3(value):
 
    global df
    
    dfglobal = pd.read_csv('base.csv',dtype={'date':'string'})
    
    fig=px.bar(dfglobal,x='date',y='value_likes',color='type', barmode='group',
        color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.deep_r, template='plotly_white'
        )

    return(fig)

    global likes 
    likes = dfglobal['value_likes'].iloc[-1]
    return(likes)```

doesn’t change the likes when the csv updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to read unformatted code on the comments, but what I was suggesting is to add likes to the global variable definition inside streamFig3, such as `global df, likes`

Comment: @VascoLudovico gotcha! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Output('likes-display', 'children'),
    [Input('interval-component', "n_intervals")]
)

def streamFig3(value):

    global df
    
    dfglobal = pd.read_csv('base.csv',dtype={'date':'string'})
    likes=dfglobal['value_likes'].iloc[-1]
    fig=px.bar(dfglobal,x='date',y='value_likes',color='type', barmode='group',
        color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.deep_r, template='plotly_white'
        )

    return fig, str(likes)
```

and also adding to the `dbc.container`

```
html.H4(id='likes-display'),
```

This will allow the likes variable to be updated every n seconds inside a callback

This answer [is based on the reply given here](https://community.plotly.com/t/callback-of-variable-for-update-in-layout/52867/2?u=jgomes_eu) by MichelH